# Replace current variable names and move them into rows

Tags: dplyr, tabulizer

After extracting tables from a PDF using `tabulizer`, my table looks like:

| A | King | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | Queen | Red |
| T | Prince | Black |

I want to move the variable names down as observations and replace them with a vector of strings with the actual column names:

| letter | rank | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | King | Blue |
| D | Queen | Red |
| T | Prince | Black |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df <- rbind(names(df), df)
colnames(df) <- c("letter", "rank", "colour")
```

output

```r
  letter   rank colour
1      A   King   Blue
2      D  Queen    Red
3      T Prince  Black
```

---

`dplyr` style:

```r
df %>% 
  rbind(colnames(.), .) %>% 
  set_names(c("letter", "rank", "colour"))
```